# Too many alarms/receivers errors

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've noticed a bunch of errors showing up in error monitoring tools, connected with FirebaseInstanceIdService:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: regist too many Broadcast Receivers
>   1   at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiverInternal(ContextImpl.java:1838)
>   2   at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1794)
>   3   at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1788)
>   4   at android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:489)
>   5   at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService.boolean zzag(android.content.Intent)(Unknown Source)
>   6

happening on HUAWEI RIO-L01 device running Android 5.1, and:

> ava.lang.SecurityException: !@Too many alarms (500) registered from pid 25905 uid 10022
>   1   at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1546)
>   2   at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1499)
>   3   at android.app.IAlarmManager$Stub$Proxy.set(IAlarmManager.java:206)
>   4   at android.app.AlarmManager.setImpl(AlarmManager.java:428)
>   5   at android.app.AlarmManager.set(AlarmManager.java:215)
>   6   at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService.void zzah(android.content.Intent)(Unknown Source)

happening on samsung SM-G800F running Android 5.1.1. Anyone know what's going on?

I suspect this is probably caused by phone vendor code and not by Firebase, but it still messes with my crash rate stats, so I'd like to work around it if possible.

Errors started with recent app release, but the FCM code it's related to is older than that, which is why I hope it's avoidable. I'm not sure what the change was that precipitated it, there was nothing directly FCM related that I can isolate.

I'm using Firebase 9.6.1, build tools 24.0.2, targetSdk 19, minSdk 14.

Here's the app gradle file (redacted to remove testing, variants, irrelevant build types):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.getkeepsafe.dexcount'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion '24.0.2'

    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'hr.doesnt.matter'
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionName '1.3.5.4'
        versionCode 13540

        multiDexEnabled true

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-android.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries true
        javaMaxHeapSize "6g" // Use gig increments depending on needs
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar', '*.aar'])
    // - SUPPORT LIBS
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:percent:24.2.1'
    // - GOOGLE SERVICES
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:9.6.1'
    // - FONTS
    compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.2.0'
    // - TOOLS
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.koushikdutta.async:androidasync:2.1.7'
    compile 'com.splunk.mint:mint:5.0.0'
    compile 'nf.fr.eraasoft:objectpool:1.1.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:r1.5.2'
    // - RX
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.trello:rxlifecycle:0.5.0'
    compile 'com.trello:rxlifecycle-components:0.5.0'

}

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force "com.android.support:support-annotations:24.2.1"
        force "com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And here's the project gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'
        classpath 'com.getkeepsafe.dexcount:dexcount-gradle-plugin:0.5.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://mint.splunk.com/gradle/" }
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us your *app.gradle* and *project.gradle*, thanks!

Comment: Gradle files added.

Comment: UPDATE: Problem seems to have been fixed, possibly with later play services or firebase libs, since it doesn't seem to happen anymore.

Comment: Congrats mate, then close the question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that subsequent library releases (Firebase 9.8.0 at least) have remedied that situation as I don't see it happening anymore. True cause remains a mystery. :)

Answer (score 0):

All libraries from firebase need this dependencie in *app.gradle*:

```
'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.6.1'
```

Adds this one and tell me if you have any error, greetings!

Comment: I have all 9.6.1 but I face this exact problem on samsung devices. I am not registering any alarms. I am also not using InstanceId service either.